# restAPI- how to format JSON value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I am getting JSON value from my server and it works well. But I want to customize my JSON value. I have two questions:

First, when I get region value, I get it like `["USA"],["Mexico"],["Canada"]`. Is there a way I can ignore the double quotes/brackets and just get the strings values like `USA, Mexico, Canada`?

Second, when I get the regDate value I get the whole data like `2018-10-31T07:53:12.000Z` instead, can I ignore some values and get it like `2018-10-31 07:53`?

```
{
  "result": "ok",
  "data": [
      {
        "idx": 1,
        "region": "[\"USA \", \"Mexico \", \"Canada \"]",
        "regDate": "2018-10-31T07:53:12.000Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far in terms of extracting the region and date values?

Comment: Is that JSON correct?  Your region is another JSON value, a bit wastefull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that your `region` data was double-encoded. In javascript, you'll want to decode that, e.g.

```
const response = {
  "result": "ok",
  "data": [
      {
        "idx": 1,
        "region": "[\"USA \", \"Mexico \", \"Canada \"]",
        "regDate": "2018-10-31T07:53:12.000Z"
      }
   ]
};

const regions = JSON.parse(response.data[0].region);
```

For time formatting, you could use the built-in Javascript `Date` type, such as..

```
const regDate = new Date(response.data[0].regDate);
const regDatestr = 
  regDate.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
  regDate.getUTCMonth() + '-' +
  regDate.getDate() + ' ' +
  regDate.getUTCHours() + ':' +
  regDate.getUTCMinutes()
;
```

If you need more functionality than the built-in, I would recommend [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You'd save the results of your JSON query to a variable `data`. Then you'd do this:

```
var countries = "";

for (var i = 0; i < data[0].region.length; i++) {
    countries += data[0].region[i];
}

var time = data[0].regDate.split("000Z");
```